# How current are near real time MODIS products maintained by GEE (MOD09GQ) ? What is the update frequency?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I'm trying to compute a near real time time series of MODIS daily NDVI from MOD09GQ for an area of interest.

I was using some download tools that got deprecated and are no longer supported (MODIStsp package).

With that I was able to get a time series that was available up to 5 days before the current date. (e.g. today is 2022-08-16, if I run the download and processing script I could get a daily NDVI time series up to 2022-08-11).

I was planning to use GEE tool to get the data now. The product page (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD09GQ) state that the data availability for this product is up to 2022-08-03. It has been like this for 3 days.

How often the MODIS near real time data availability is updated?

Does it lags behind the current date for two weeks, always? I could not find any documentation about this topic with the research I did.

Comment: The given data availability in the data catalog might not be the most up to date for some products. Also keep in mind, that both MODIS sensors are not delivering consistent data anymore since they are in the process of being decomissioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, Earth Engine checks for new data in public datasets at least daily, and copies it into Earth Engine as soon as it is discovered. When current data is missing, this might be for reasons like:

- the data provider has not published the data at all, yet
- technical problems at the data provider prevent Earth Engine from obtaining the data
- the format in which the data is provided has changed, and Earth Engine must be adjusted to adapt
- technical problems with Earth Engine's data pipelines

I asked about this particular case and [there are issues with the capacity of LP DAAC](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/news/lp-daac-data-access/), the service which provides MODIS images. Once Earth Engine successfully retrieves copies of the images, they will be available in the Earth Engine catalog.

Comment: I was facing frequent time outs and interruptions with the previous tools too. So is a LP DAAC side issue. Thanks.